# EditText con salto de linea deja de estar vacío

Tags: java, android

Veréis, tengo el siguiente código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    btnTranslate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String texto = textTranslate();

            if (etBeforeTranslate.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                ivLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logotipoangry);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "¡Ay que agobio! Intridici il tixti, anda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                Translates = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Translates");
                registerTranslates();
                ivLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logotipo);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TranslateActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("texto", texto);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        }
    });
```

El problema lo tengo en el condicional, que compruebo que si el EditText está vacío, me ejecute ese código. El problema viene cuando hago un salto de linea, aunque la linea esté vacía, la aplicación se cree que hay texto metido, ¿como puedo decirle que aunque la persona pulse enter sin escribir texto, sigue estando vacío y no le deje avanzar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes validar que este vacio aun cuando tenga espacios en blanco haciendo un `trim()`

```
etBeforeTranslate.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0
```

Comment: Rápido y conciso, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

En este caso te sugiero restringir el `EditText` a una sola línea, definiendo estas propiedades en el `EditText`, no permitirá dar <kbd>Enter</kbd> y siempre permanecerá en la misma linea, de esta forma no se insertarían espacios:

```
<EditText 
    ...
    ...
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    ...
    ...
    >
</EditText>
```

Además considera agregar la validación para el caso cuando se insertan espacios mediante la "barra espaciadora", usando `.trim()` para eliminar los espacios.

```
if(etBeforeTranslate.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
 // Vacío.
}else{
  // Tiene contenido.
}
```

Comment: Pero es un Edittext largo, por lo que entonces si le doy restricción de 1 linea no tendría sentido tenerlo a este tamaño...